# Ito formula and confusion with the differential operator $d$

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma, differential-equations

Thanks for visiting my question.

Im am currently working on this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.02523) and I am stuck at page 21 (Theorem 14 proof).
First these SDE's were defined:
\begin{align*}
    dZ_t&=Y_tdt\\
    dY_t&=X_tdt\\
    dX_t&=A(t,X_t)dt+B(t,X_t)dW_t
\end{align*}
And we define "the value of the contract" by:
$P=de^{-rt} v(t,x,y,z)$
Then the authors use the general Ito formula to derive:
($v_x$ is the derivative with respect to x)
$dv(t,x,y,z)=v_tdt+v_xdx+\frac{1}{2}v_{xx}d[x,x]+v_ydy+v_zdz$
up to this point I understand the proof.
Then they want to calculate $dP$ which is given without further explanation by:
$dP=e^{-rt}(-rv+v_t+\frac{1}{2} v_{xx}B(t,X_t)^2+v_xA(t,X_t)+xv_y+yv_z  )dt+ v_xB(t,X_t)e^{-rt}dW_t$
I dont unterstand how to get to this formula

**My attempt**:
starting from
$dv(t,x,y,z)=v_tdt+v_xdx+\frac{1}{2}v_{xx}d[x,x]+v_ydy+v_zdz$
i have plugged in the SDE's:
e.g. $dz=ydt$, $dy=xdt$, $dx=A(t,X_t)dt+B(t,X_t)dW_t$ and $d[x,x]=B(t,X_t)^2dt$
$\Rightarrow dv(t,x,y,z)=(v_t+\frac{1}{2} v_{xx}B(t,X_t)^2+v_xA(t,X_t)+xv_y+yv_z  )dt+v_xB(t,X_t)dW_t$

Now i used:
$P=de^{-rt} v(t,x,y,z)=(de^{-rt})v(t,x,y,z)+e^{-rt} (dv(t,x,y,z))$ **Is this correct?**
assuming this is correct and with our results from bevor we get:
$P=e^{-rt}(-rv+v_t+\frac{1}{2} v_{xx}B(t,X_t)^2+v_xA(t,X_t)+xv_y+yv_z  )dt+ v_xB(t,X_t)e^{-rt}dW_t$
But that is the same formula that the authors get for $dP$
So there must be a mistake

I dont realy understand how to handle $P=de^{-rt} v(t,x,y,z)$ and $dP=d(de^{-rt} v(t,x,y,z))$

Comment: I think when they write $P=de^{-rt} v(t,x,y,z)$, they in fact mean $P=e^{-rt} v(t,x,y,z)$, because writing $P=de^{-rt} v(t,x,y,z)$ doesn't really make sense (to me). So your working seems correct to me. We must have that: $$P=P_0+dP=P_0+d\left(e^{-rt}v(t,x,y,z)\right)$$

Comment: If $P_0=0$, then we have similar situation to $W_0=0$ for a Standard Brownian Motion and we can write $W_t=\int_{h=0}^{h=t}1dW_h$, some people would write $dW_t$ as a short hand for $\int_{h=0}^{h=t}1dW_h$, and then we have the confusing situation where we can write $W_t=dW_t$. Maybe that's what's going on in this paper, if $P_0=0$, then we can basically write $P=dP$, which is incredibly confusing.

Comment: thanks for your response! this is really confusing. Is my calculation ($dP=de^{-rt} v(t,x,y,z)=(de^{-rt})v(t,x,y,z)+e^{-rt} (dv(t,x,y,z))$) then correct?

Comment: Yep, I think your calc is correct.